# Como pegar os links de um nav com JavaScript e adicionar uma classe?

Tags: javascript, dom

Tenho o seguinte `nav`:

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="">1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">2</a></li>
     <li><a href="">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

e o código JavaScript:

```js
var linkElement = document.querySelector('nav a');

linkElement.classList.add('blue');
```

Mas ao fazer isso ele adiciona a classe apenas no primeiro elemento.

Se eu faço assim:

```js
var linkElement = document.querySelectorAll('li a');
```

ou

```js
var linkElement = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Como faço para adicionar a classe em todos os links ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na sua primeira tentativa você só conseguiu alterar do primeiro elemento da lista porque o `querySelector` obtém apenas o primeiro elemento encontrado do documento.

Para obter todos os elementos você deve utilizar a função [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). O que essa função faz é retornar um Array contendo todos os elementos encontrados. Foi lançado um erro na segunda tentativa onde você chama esta função, justamente porque você tentou utilizar o atributo `classList` que não existe em arrays.

Na terceira tentativa, o erro também foi lançado pelo mesmo motivo já que a função `getElementsByTagName` retorna um Array contendo todos os elementos com a `tag` que você especificou.

Para que o código funcione, você deve percorrer os elementos obtidos do Array através de um laço `for`, dessa forma:

```js
var linkElement = document.querySelectorAll('nav a');

for (element of linkElement){
    element.classList.add('blue');
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="">1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">2</a></li>
     <li><a href="">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```